# Construct a Compact set of Real numbers whose limit points form a countable set

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

What do you think about this set?

K = 0 $ \cup$ {1/n : n $\epsilon$ Natural numbers}

It has one limit point which is zero, so it is countable and it is compact. Is this correct?

Also, do you have any ideas of compact sets that come to mind whom you can count there limit points, and they have a countably infinite amount of them?

Let G = 0 $\cup$ {1/n : n $\epsilon$ Natural numbers}

Let {$G_n$} Be a collection of sets Such that N $\cup$ {N + 1/r} For r = 1,2.3.... and N = 0,1,2......

Let me explain, you first start with N = 0. For N = 0 you calculate all the values of r. For N = 0 that will give you a limit point of 0. For N = 1, you do the same, and that should give you a limit point of 1, for N = 2 the same, so on and so on.

I don't know if wrote the proper notation for the set I'm envisioning, but I feel like it gets the job done. What do ya'll think? Also, can you guys think of any other ones?

Comment: I'm guessing they want you to stretch your understanding by finding a set with a countably *infinite* set of limit points. To see how this would work, extend your idea to two limit points, then to three ...

Comment: Does countable include the possibility of finite? I would say your example depends on what counts as being countable.

Comment: HINT: Start by doing for every integer what you did for $0$. Then think about how to modify that to make it compact.

Comment: @Clayton: Yes, though some people sloppily use *countable* when they mean *countably infinite*, and I suspect that that’s the case in this exercise.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: That won't yield a **compact** set. But one can modify the construction to accomodate for this.

Comment: @PhoemueX: I meant it only as a starting point, but I probably should have said so. Fortunately, I can still edit it.

Comment: I just created a set I think is good. What do you think, guys?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer depends on countable including finite.  Some definitions accept it, some do not.  An easy way to get countably infinite limit points is $K \cup \frac 1m+\frac1n, m,n \in \Bbb N$  Now each $\frac 1n$ is a limit point.